# Strange keywords for documents with "CLF"

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I'm using fts and observed strange behavior when the text contains a string "clf". For some reason keywords created for documents with "clf" string behave differently then almost identical documents with some other string in place of "clf". Bellow is code to recreate described behavior

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test1](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [data] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_test1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG test_catalog;

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].test1  
(  
    data
)  
KEY INDEX [PK_test1] ON test_catalog

insert into dbo.test1 values (1, N'17 12 CLF'), (2, N'17 13 bbb'), (3, N'17 129 CLF'), (4, N'17 139 aaa')
```

Then when we query keywords created

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document( DB_ID('db_name'), OBJECT_ID('dbo.test1') )
```

we can see that keywords created for document with "clf" are different then with "aaa" and "bbb". For example for document 4 there is keyword "139" but for document 3 there is not "129" and there is only "17 129 clf".

What is the reason for this behavior? Is there a simple way to force fts to behave the same way for strings with and without "clf"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using fulltext search on technical values could be challenging.
The stop-word-list and the dictionary language affect the search.

I disabled in my project the stoplist (off) and set the language to neutral.

When you are searching with "contains" and you are using "*" in the words, then remember this:
SQL-Server could only do a prefix search!

see here:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

with neutral language and no stoplist it looks equal:

document 3:

```
129
17
17 129
clf
nn129
nn17
nn17129
```

document 4:

```
139
17
17 139
aaa
nn139
nn17
nn17139
```

Comment: How it will affect search (using CONTAINS) text with accents?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it should rely on the collation settings.